# Smack connect() hangs up

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I'm trying to implement a simple XMPP messenger using Asmack API on Android. 
Here's the code:

```
    private final String XMPP_SERVER = "jabber.org";
    private final String USERNAME = "letstest@jabber.org";
    private final String PASSWORD = "";

    SmackConfiguration.setPacketReplyTimeout(PACKET_REPLY_TIMEOUT);
    config = new ConnectionConfiguration(XMPP_SERVER, PORT);
    config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(false);
    config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled);
    connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
    try 
    {
        connection.connect();
    } 
    catch (XMPPException e) 
    {           
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
```

The problem is that connection.connect() method hangs up and doesn't respond to anything though it appears to be running. How can I fix it?

Cheers, Ivan.

Comment: Where you able to solve this? I think I have the same issue...

Comment: Even I have the same, has anyone got solution?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an event loop running somewhere so the process doesn't just exit?